# Aligned with or Aligns to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, difference

I want to replace: I am interested in this bachelor because **it is aligned with my targets** by
I am interested in this bachelor because **it aligns to my targets**. However, I am not sure if by doing so the meaning of the first sentence remains.

Answer (score 1):

Your original

> I am interested in this bachelor because it is aligned with my targets

seems better as to *align* something in general means to make it parallel to something else so *align to* seems slightly odd.

However I would prefer

> I am interested in this bachelor's degree because it is aligned with my targets

as when I first read your example I thought you were interested in an unmarried man until I got to the word *it*. There is nothing wrong with yours but it made me pause unnecessarily.